# Execute batch in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have a batch that is run in putty.  How can I run it using java in eclipse. Can it be executed in a command prompt?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Run an external program  from java? Or run an exernal program from eclipse? Also that program must run on a different machine?

Comment: If it is the only thing you want to do, pick some different language. Bash or some other scripting lang. is much more suitable. Or just plain old bat files.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
AWSBatch client = AWSBatchClientBuilder.standard().build();
SubmitJobRequest request = new SubmitJobRequest().withJobName("example").withJobQueue("HighPriority").withJobDefinition("sleep60");
SubmitJobResult response = client.submitJob(request);
```

Link info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/batch/AWSBatch.html#listJobs-com.amazonaws.services.batch.model.ListJobsRequest-